# Short Story about a giant bird that comes from another galaxy

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a short story about a giant bird that comes from another galaxy and all the scientists who talk to him commit suicide. It was something about the bird coming to this galaxy to die or something like that.

I think it was written between the 60s and 70s. I thought it was from the author [A. E. van Vogt](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/A._E._van_Vogt) but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Sounds like some versions of the Simurgh.

Comment: Or maybe the Ziz. The two get mixed up in my head.

Comment: no relation to the "Great Bird of the Galaxy"

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82353/giant-bird-in-space might be relevant

Comment: There are a number of golden age stories about the planets being eggs and a giant space bird turns up for the hatching, but I must admit I can't remember any in which a giant bird comes to our galaxy to die.

Comment: I also thought that van Vogt had written something about a Simurgh-like bird from deep space, but I can't find it.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots "And Lo! The Bird" doesn't involve scientists that commit suicide after talking to the creature, though. (Though perhaps this is a case of conflation of that and another story, as happens with some story ID questions.)

Comment: That's fair. I didn't see any indication of the suicides either, but I had little time to research.

Comment: I wonder if this isn't a distorted memory of "[The Deathbird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Deathbird)" by Harlan Ellison.